# Concourse - Pipeline returns "Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref"

Tags: concourse-pipeline, concourse-git-resource, concourse-task, concourse-resource-types

I am running a maven release plugin in concourse pipeline. Our Git is in GitHub Enterprise and so is our Artifactory.

I am getting the resource, I am able to build it and release a snapshot to Artifactory using deploy. But when I go for the release concourse fails with ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref

Here is my CI code that does the release:

```
- name: build-release
  plan:
  - get: tool-v2
    params: {depth: 1}
    #passed: [ build-docker-image ]
  - task: build
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source:
          repository: adoptopenjdk/openjdk11
          tag: "latest"
      inputs:
      - name: tool-v2
      outputs:
      - name: built-artifact-release
      run:
        path: /bin/bash
        args:
          - -c
          - |
            set -e
            apt-get update && apt-get install -y git
            cd tool-v2
            git config --global user.email "emailadd"
            git config --global user.name "Service Account"
            ./mvnw release:clean release:prepare -B
            ./mvnw release:perform -B -Darguments="-Dmaven.javadoc.skip=true -DscmCommentPrefix='[skip ci]'"
            ./git push --tags origin main:release
```

Here is the error I am getting in the pipeline:

```
INFO] [INFO] Replacing main artifact with repackaged archive
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] [INFO] Total time:  42.868 s
[INFO] [INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-20T16:52:23Z
[INFO] [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Checking in modified POMs...
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /tmp/build/80754af9/tool-v2 && git add -- pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /tmp/build/80754af9/tool-v2
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /tmp/build/80754af9/tool-v2 && git rev-parse --show-toplevel
[INFO] Working directory: /tmp/build/80754af9/tool-v2
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /tmp/build/80754af9/tool-v2 && git status --porcelain .
[INFO] Working directory: /tmp/build/80754af9/tool-v2
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? pom.xml.releaseBackup
[WARNING] Ignoring unrecognized line: ?? release.properties
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /tmp/build/80754af9/tool-v2 && git commit --verbose -F /tmp/maven-scm-1405815331.commit pom.xml
[INFO] Working directory: /tmp/build/80754af9/tool-v2
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /tmp/build/80754af9/tool-v2 && git symbolic-ref HEAD
[INFO] Working directory: /tmp/build/80754af9/xtool-v2
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  59.483 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-04-20T16:52:23Z
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-release-plugin:2.5.3:prepare (default-cli) on project tool-v2: An error is occurred in the checkin process: Exception while executing SCM command. Detecting the current branch failed: fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My resource:

```
resources:
  - name: tool-v2
    type: git
    check_every: 1h
    source:
      uri: git@github_url.git
      disable_ci_skip: false
      branch: pipeline
      version:
        ref: commit-sha
      private_key:
```

I tried all the available options. I tried adding depth from 1 to 100 still the same error. I added  version: ref: commit-sha and the error still remains.

Comment: You are getting "Ignoring unrecognized line" warnings - I wonder if your YAML is invalid, and is causing a knock-on error. Is that worth looking into?

Comment: Can you speak here a bit about what `git symbolic-ref HEAD` is intended to do? That seems to be the cause of the error.